# How to create a fixed control panel in the bottom of a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How can I create a fixed control panel in the bottom of a web page?:

[image]

The grey coloured content should be scrollable (vertically). But the pink coloured panel should always be visible.

I am using Material-UI to sketch a design of my web page, because I am not a designer. I would appreciate a solution that uses Material-UI. But if Material-UI does not support it, then CSS solution is fine too.

Comment: `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`

Comment: Is your problem only with styling? or you're asking how to achieve that using React components ?

Comment: Check this for Material UI, AppBar (works as bottom bar also)   https://material-ui.com/demos/app-bar/

Comment: @Tarreq: This is what I was searching for. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try `position: fixed; bottom: 0;`. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set the control panel to fixed position :

`position: fixed`

Afterwards, position it at the bottom of the page:

`bottom: 0`

Be careful though, if you have any content on the footer of your page it may overlap it, so use it wisely :)

I have created a small example here (without Material UI) : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fixed-menu